# What happens if all the Values in the SORT column in MySQL Query are blank or Empty or NULL?

Tags: sql, mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a query like this,

`SELECT colA, colB, colC, colD FROM myTable  ORDER BY colC ASC;`

Here, in myTable, all the values in the column `colC` are Empty/Blank/NULL. Now, how MySQL will behave in this scenario? I know the query will still execute without errors. But I am curious about how the SORTING will behave if all values of that mentioned column are Empty/Blank/NULL. On what column, the SORTING will happen on the result set?

`SELECT colA, colB, colC, colD FROM myTable  ORDER BY colC ASC;`

Comment: Whatever you mean with "empty" and "blank", it's just regular data. Sort depends on data type and collation (if text type). Other DBMS have `NULL FIRST` or `NULL LAST` modifiers, MySQL doesn't so it'll always use its default, which apparently is that [NULL is the smallest](https://dbfiddle.uk/KtIxXygC): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: This does seem like something you could have tested for yourself or even look up in the manual

Comment: Also Empty/Blank/NULL are normally or at least can be 3 distinct and different values.

Answer (score 1):

If all the values in `colC` are the same, the rows will be returned in an arbitrary order.
Please note that arbitrary isn't necessarily random - its not likely you'll get a different order of rows each time you run the query, however there's no way for the database to guarantee any particular order of the rows if the column used in the `order by` clause contains the same values in all the rows returned by the query.

Please note that `null` is **not** `blank` nither `empty`, but rather `unknown` - a string column such as `char` or `varchar` might contain an empty string - but an empty string is not equivalent to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The rows with empty/blank/NULL values in `colC` will likely appear together at either the beginning or the end of the sorted result set, depending on the specific implementation or version of MySQL being used.